# Jenkins on Kubernetes - working directory not accessible using workspaceVolume dynamicPVC

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pvc

I'm running Jenkins on EKS cluster with [k8s plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/) and i'd like to write a **declarative** pipeline in which I specify the pod template in each stage. So a basic example would be the following, in which in the first stage a file is created and in the second one is printed :

```
pipeline{
  agent none
  stages {  
    stage('First sample') {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          label 'mvn-pod'
          yaml """
spec:
  containers:
  - name: maven
    image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine
            """
                        }
                    }
        steps {
            container('maven'){
                sh "echo 'hello' > test.txt"
            }
        }
      }
      
      
    stage('Second sample') {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          label 'bysbox-pod'
          yaml """
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
            """
        }
      }
      steps {
        container('busybox'){
            sh "cat test.txt"
        }
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

This clearly doesn't work since the two pods don't have any kind of shared memory. Reading [this doc](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/kubernetes/) I realized I can use `workspaceVolume dynamicPVC ()` in the yaml declaration of the pod so that the plugin creates and manages a `persistentVolumeClaim` in which hopefully i can write the data I need to share between stages.

Now, with `workspaceVolume dynamicPVC (...)` both `pv` and `pvc` are successfully created but the pod goes on error and terminates. In particular, the pods provisioned is the following :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
    runUrl: job/test-libraries/job/sample-k8s/12/
  creationTimestamp: "2020-08-07T08:57:09Z"
  deletionGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  deletionTimestamp: "2020-08-07T08:58:09Z"
  labels:
    jenkins: slave
    jenkins/label: bibibu
  name: bibibu-ggb5h-bg68p
  namespace: jenkins-slaves
  resourceVersion: "29184450"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/jenkins-slaves/pods/bibibu-ggb5h-bg68p
  uid: 1c1e78a5-fcc7-4c86-84b1-8dee43cf3f98
spec:
  containers:
  - image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: maven
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /home/jenkins/agent
      name: workspace-volume
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-5bt8c
      readOnly: true
  - env:
    - name: JENKINS_SECRET
      value: ...
    - name: JENKINS_AGENT_NAME
      value: bibibu-ggb5h-bg68p
    - name: JENKINS_NAME
      value: bibibu-ggb5h-bg68p
    - name: JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR
      value: /home/jenkins/agent
    - name: JENKINS_URL
      value: ...
    image: jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: jnlp
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 256Mi
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /home/jenkins/agent
      name: workspace-volume
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-5bt8c
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  nodeName: ...
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Never
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: workspace-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: pvc-bibibu-ggb5h-bg68p
  - name: default-token-5bt8c
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-5bt8c
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-08-07T08:57:16Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-08-07T08:57:16Z"
    message: 'containers with unready status: [jnlp]'
    reason: ContainersNotReady
    status: "False"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-08-07T08:57:16Z"
    message: 'containers with unready status: [jnlp]'
    reason: ContainersNotReady
    status: "False"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-08-07T08:57:16Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://9ed5052e9755ee4f974704fa4b74f2d89702283a4437e60a9945cf4ec7d6da68
    image: jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4
    imageID: docker-pullable://jenkins/inbound-agent@sha256:62f48a12d41e02e557ee9f7e4ffa82c77925b817ec791c8da5f431213abc2828
    lastState: {}
    name: jnlp
    ready: false
    restartCount: 0
    state:
      terminated:
        containerID: docker://9ed5052e9755ee4f974704fa4b74f2d89702283a4437e60a9945cf4ec7d6da68
        exitCode: 1
        finishedAt: "2020-08-07T08:57:35Z"
        reason: Error
        startedAt: "2020-08-07T08:57:35Z"
  - containerID: docker://96f747a132ee98f7bf2488bd3cde247380aea5dd6f84bdcd7e6551dbf7c08943
    image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine
    imageID: docker-pullable://maven@sha256:3ab854089af4b40cf3f1a12c96a6c84afe07063677073451c2190cdcec30391b
    lastState: {}
    name: maven
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2020-08-07T08:57:35Z"
  hostIP: 10.108.171.224
  phase: Running
  podIP: 10.108.171.158
  qosClass: Burstable
  startTime: "2020-08-07T08:57:16Z"
```

Retrieving logs from jnlp container on the pod with `kubectl logs name-of-the-pod -c jnlp -n jenkins-slaves` led me towards this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The specified working directory should be fully accessible to the remoting executable (RWX): /home/jenkins/agent
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager.verifyDirectory(WorkDirManager.java:249)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager.initializeWorkDir(WorkDirManager.java:201)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.startEngine(Engine.java:288)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.startEngine(Engine.java:264)
        at hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main.main(Main.java:284)
        at hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main._main(Main.java:279)
        at hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main.main(Main.java:231)
```

I also tried to specify the `accessModes` as parameter of `dynamicPVC`, but the error is the same. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The docker image being used is configured to run as a non-root user `jenkins`. By default PVCs will be created only allowing root-user access.

This can be configured using the [security context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#configure-volume-permission-and-ownership-change-policy-for-pods), e.g.

```
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 1000
  runAsGroup: 1000
  fsGroup: 1000
```

(The jenkins user in that image is ID 1000)